# Background color with variations

Tags: css

Is there a way to get this background color without setting the image as background? I want to know if there is a way to add those shadows, besides doing background-color:cyan.

[image]

Comment: And you have tried what? You can do this with `background-gradient` it is called I think. have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using Power bullet presentation as per my knowledge ...

Here you can choose any colour and you can get this colour as HTML code ...
like I get this one as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var InternetExplorer = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
function powerbullet_DoFSCommand(command, args) { 
    var map = InternetExplorer ? powerbullet : document.powerbullet; 
    if (command=="home" ) 
        map.Rewind(); 
    else if ( command=="zoom" ) 
        map.Zoom(parseInt(args)); 
   else if (command == "message") 
        alert(args);
   else if (command == "pan") 
        map.Pan(parseInt(args)); 
   else if (command == "parse") 
        eval(args); 
}
//--></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
<!-- 
Sub powerbullet_FSCommand(ByVal command, ByVal args)
  call powerbullet_DoFSCommand(command, args)
end sub
-->
</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Nothing(){
}
//--> </script>

<style type="text/css">
 body {text-align:center;}
 div.center {text-align:center;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="Nothing()" bgcolor=#FFFFFF leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<div class="center">
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" ID="powerbullet"
  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#4,0,0,0"
  WIDTH=760px HEIGHT=497px>
  <PARAM name=movie VALUE="__PREVIEW.swf">
  <PARAM NAME=menu VALUE=false> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
  <PARAM NAME=scale VALUE=exactfit> <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=opaque>
  <EMBED NAME="powerbullet" WIDTH=760px HEIGHT=497px src="__PREVIEW.swf"
  menu=false quality=high scale=exactfit wmode=opaque
  TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></EMBED>
</object>
</div>
<center> </center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

And the colour you get by this code is as it is showing less darkness but it can be adjusted:[image]
You can download powerbullet from here : http://powerbullet.com

Comment: Darkness may coming like little bit less but it can be adjusted easily.